# What is the cheapest valid transaction?

Tags: web3js, transactions, gas

What is the cheapest valid transaction, in terms of gas used? Is there a "no op" kind of transaction that I can construct?

If so, how would I construct this with web3?

Comment: note there are Ethereum-based chains other than Ethereum itself, so if you are looking to prototype something for minimal cost, I wonder if it would be cheaper to run the prototype on a different chain, or a testnet.

Answer (score 3):

The cheapest would be to send a transaction with no `calldata`. It would consume 21,000 gas if sent to a non-contract account. Any other transaction is bound to consume more than 21,000 gas.